# How to set notifications listed under settings -> notifications?

Tags: iphone, uilocalnotification

i have an app that is using local notifications, and its working all fine, it is generating notifications very well, now i want to turn it off from settings but its not been listed under settings -> notifications any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can design your own Settings.bundle and you application settings will appear in Settings -> Applications -> Your app
And in your application you can change this setting and handle it in your app to stop generating local notifications.

Comment: Yes you could do that,except that you need to start your to check if the setting and then cancel any LocalNotification. Thus when a user thinks he/she stop you app from sending notification some could still popup if your isn't started again after the settings was changes.

Answer (score 2):

Only push notification are in the settings screen.
You have to do this from within you own app.