# Local Push Notification Settings and notification section in device settings

Tags: iphone, apple-push-notifications

I am using local push notifications in my app. I need the users to have an option in the push notification section of the device settings page. Currently my app is not listed under the notification section. Is there a way so that apps with local push notifications would also be listed in this section. Or, the notification section only shows apps with Apple Push Notification Service.(Remote APNS)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is already [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6953968/how-to-set-notifications-listed-under-settings-notifications). You can't be listed on settings->notifications, you handle it on your own in your app. But you can also (as mentioned in the previous answer) make your own Settings bundle (Apple documentation [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Preferences/Preferences.html)).